# Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm getting the error:

> "Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in" on line 183

From this code:

```
$getvidids = $ci->db->query(
    "SELECT * FROM videogroupids " . 
    "WHERE videogroupid='$videogroup' AND used='0' LIMIT 10");

foreach ($getvidids->result() as $row){
    $vidid = $row['videoid'];              //This is line 183
}
```

Anyone know what's wrong with the above code? Or what this error means?

Comment: The error is saying your variable `$row` is of type stdClass, and that you should access its member variables using `$row->videoid` rather than `$row['videoid']`.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

CodeIgniter returns result rows as objects, not arrays. From the [user guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html):

> #### result()
>
> ---
>
> This function returns the query result as an array of **objects**, or **an empty array** on failure.

You'll have to access the fields using the following notation:

```
foreach ($getvidids->result() as $row) {
    $vidid = $row->videoid;
}
```

Answer (score 18):

if you really want an array instead you can use:

```
$getvidids->result_array()
```

which would return the same information as an associative array.

Answer (score 0):

**Controller** (Example: User.php)

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Users extends CI_controller
{

    // Table
    protected  $table = 'users';

    function index()
    {
        $data['users'] = $this->model->ra_object($this->table);
        $this->load->view('users_list', $data);
    }
}
```

**View** (Example: users_list.php)

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Surname</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <?php foreach($users as $user) : ?>
            <tr>
            <td><?php echo $user->name; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $user->surname; ?></th>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<!-- // User table -->
```

Answer (score -3):

Sorry.Though it is a bit late but hope it would help others as well .
Always use the stdClass object.e.g

```
 $getvidids = $ci->db->query("SELECT * FROM videogroupids WHERE videogroupid='$videogroup'   AND used='0' LIMIT 10");

foreach($getvidids->result() as $key=>$myids)
{

  $vidid[$key] = $myids->videoid;  // better methodology to retrieve and store multiple records in arrays in loop
 }
```

Comment: Why would you drop in 2 years after an answer was accepted and leave the same answer?