# Cannot use object of type stdClass as array(php)

Tags: php, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5412924/fatal-error-cannot-use-object-of-type-stdclass-as-array-in)

Please I keep getting this error:
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in C:\XAMMP\xampp\htdocs\Yemi\geograph\table.php on line 31

This is the php I am trying to run:

[image: php code]

Comment: Please paste the actual code here, and not some screenshot of your code. Thanks

Comment: Yes, please post the actual code. We rely heavily on copy/pasting code examples to provide answers with bugfixes and annotation.

Comment: The response from 'Click' solved the problem. Question answered. Forum please note...

Comment: @akinboj when an answer solves your problem you are supposed to tick the green check mark next to it. And please: next time use the search function before asking a question that has been asked and answered numerous times before. There is a reason we force http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice on you and asked you to do your homework prior to asking. And you are also not supposed to ignore the suggestions we show when you type in your question.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You are actually trying to access the object as array.

I can guess you are having problem when you are using `json_decode` which is returning an object and inside the `foreach` loop you are trying to access it like an associative array.

Passing the second argument as `true` to `json_decode` force it to return associative array.

Make the below change.

Change your this code line

```
$items = json_decode($contents);
```

To

```
$items = json_decode($contents, true);
```