# Decoding json and re-inserting into array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have this array extracted from a db record using Laravel:

```
$deal = DB::table('deals')->where('id', Input::json('id'))->get();

Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 10001
            [status] => 1
            [images] => {main: '1.jpg',portfolio: ['1.jpg','2.jpg','3.jpg','4.jpg']}
        )
)
```

Before returning the data to the client, I need the `[images]` value to be json_decoded, and re-inserted into the object. I tried this:

```
$json = $deal[0]['images'];
$images = json_decode($json);
```

Which already returns this error: `Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5412924/fatal-error-cannot-use-object-of-type-stdclass-as-array-in)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

(Object you have to access with `->` and arrays with `["key"]`)

```
$json = $deal[0]->images;
$deal[0]->images = json_decode($json);
```

Also for more information about how to access an array see the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

And a quote from there:

> An existing array can be modified by explicitly setting values in it.
>   This is done by assigning values to the array, specifying the key in brackets. The key can also be omitted, resulting in an empty pair of brackets ([]).

```
$arr[key] = value;
$arr[] = value;
// key may be an integer or string
// value may be any value of any type
```

And for more information about how to access an object property see the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/sdo.sample.getset.php

And a quote from there:

> Data object properties can be accessed using the object property access syntax. The following sets the company name to 'Acme'.

```
<?php
    $company->name = 'Acme';
?>
```

Also your JSON string doesn't seems to be valid see: http://jsonlint.com/ And insert your JSON string

Comment: that removed the error thanks! But it turns it into a string; how do I re-insert back into the array as an object?

Comment: @greener - That turns *what* into a string? Nothing in this code turns anything into a string...

Answer (score 1):

`$deal[0]` is an object, so you'll have to use object syntax after that instead of array syntax:

```
<?php
$deal[0]->images = json_decode($deal[0]->images);
```