# Product category function not working in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm making a website in CodeIgniter and I'm trying to make a menu bar with all the categories, and when you click on a certain category it must show all the products that are in that category but its not really working.

The categories are showing on the category side menu bar, but when I click on a certain category link its going to the right view page but instead of the product information I'm getting this error:

```
  A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Error

Message: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Filename: views/category.php

Line Number: 41

Backtrace:
```

Line 41 in category.php is this line:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>/Product/details/<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>">
```

So I'm guessing it can't echo product detail information?
Here is my Allecadeaus controller to echo products:

```
<?php

    class AlleCadeausController extends CI_Controller {

        public function index()
        {
            $this->load->model('Product_model');
            $this->load->model('allecadeaus_model');
            $data['products'] = $this->allecadeaus_model->get_products();
            $this->load->view('allecadeaus', $data);
        }
    }
```

My Allecadeaus_model model file which I use to echo products:

```
<?php
class Allecadeaus_model extends CI_Model {


 public function __construct()
 {
parent::__construct();
}

public function get_products()
{
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM products'); 

    $result = $query->result_array();

    return $result;

}

}
```

category.php view file:

```
<?php   include_once ('templates/header.php');  ?>

<!-- Alle cadeaus gele title bovenaan pagina -->

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 bg-warning" style="font-size:25px">
            <center>Alle cadeaus</center>
        </div>
        </div>
</div>

 <hr />

<br>

<!-- Cadeau categorie side menu -->
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div id="categorymenu">
                    <center>  <h3>Categorieën</h3> </center>
                    <ul class="list-group">
                         <?php foreach (get_categories_h() as $category) : ?>
             <li class="list-group-item">
                 <a href="<?php echo base_url().'Product/category/' . $category->id; ?>"> <?php echo $category->name; ?></a>
            </li>
         <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>




<!-- Laat cadeau zien op alle cadeaus pagina -->
<div class="col-md-8">
<?php foreach($products as $product) : ?>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div id="product">
        <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>/Product/details/<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>">
          <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>upload/<?php echo $product['product_foto_thumb']; ?>">
        </a>
        <div class="product_naam"><?php echo $product['product_naam']; ?></div>
        <div class="ophaal_plaats">
           <?php  echo $product['ophaal_plaats']; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="aangeboden_door">
            <p>Aangeboden door: Peter</p>
              </div>
        </div>
        </div>


<?php endforeach; ?>

</div>



<div class="clearfix"></div>

 <?php   include_once ('templates/footer.php');  ?>
```

My whole allecadeaus.php view file:

```
<?php   include_once ('templates/header.php');  ?>

<!-- Alle cadeaus gele title bovenaan pagina -->

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 bg-warning" style="font-size:25px">
            <center>Alle cadeaus</center>
        </div>
        </div>
</div>

 <hr />

<br>

<!-- Cadeau categorie side menu -->
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div id="categorymenu">
                    <center>  <h3>Categorieën</h3> </center>
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <?php foreach (get_categories_h() as $category) : ?>
                            <li class="list-group-item">
                               <a href="<?php echo base_url('Product/category/'.$category['id']);?>"> <?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>

                            </li>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>




<!-- Laat cadeau zien op alle cadeaus pagina -->
<div class="col-md-8">
<?php foreach($products as $product) : ?>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div id="product">
        <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>/Product/details/<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>">
          <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>upload/<?php echo $product['product_foto_thumb']; ?>">
        </a>
        <div class="product_naam"><?php echo $product['product_naam']; ?></div>
        <div class="ophaal_plaats">
           <?php  echo $product['ophaal_plaats']; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="aangeboden_door">
            <p>Aangeboden door: Peter</p>
              </div>
        </div>
        </div>


<?php endforeach; ?>

</div>



<div class="clearfix"></div>

 <?php   include_once ('templates/footer.php');  ?>
```

My Product.php controller file:

```
<?php
 defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
 class Product extends CI_Controller { 


    var $data = array();

     public function index()
 {

  //Laad kado uploaden view
  $this->load->view('product_form', $this->data);
 }

 public function details($product_id)
 {
  //load the Product_model
  $this->load->model('Product_model');

  //call function getdata in de Product_model
  $data['userdetail_list'] = $this->Product_model->getdata();

  //get product details
  $data['product'] = $this->Product_model->get_product_details($product_id);

  //laad view
  $data['main_content'] = 'details';
  $this->load->view('details',$data); 
 }
 //categorie product function
 public function category($id)
 {
  $data['title'] = 'Category';
  $data['page'] = 'Product/category';
  $data['category'] = $this->Category_model->findByCategory($id);
  $data['products'] = $this->Product_model->findByCategory($id);
  $this->Category_model->findByCategory($id);
  $this->load->view('category', $data);
 }

 public function __construct()
 {
  parent::__construct();
  $this->load->model('Product_model');
  $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
 }
```

My Product_model file:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Product_model extends CI_model {

    public function saveProduct($data) { 
        $this->db->insert('products', $data);
        $product_id = $this->db->insert_id();
        return $product_id;
    }
      public function getdata()
    {
        $this->db->select('users.user_id,users.email,users.voornaam,products.product_id,products.category_id,products.product_naam');
        $this->db->from('users');
        $this->db->join('products','products.user_id = users.user_id');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if($query->num_rows()>0)
        {
           return $query->result_array();
        }
    }

    public function get_product_details($product_id) {
        $arrReturn = array();
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('products');
        $this->db->where('product_id', $product_id);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query->result_array();
        if (!empty($result)) {
            $arrReturn = $result[0];
        }
        return $arrReturn;
    }


    /*
      Get categories
     */
    public function get_categories(){
        $this->db->select('*'); 
        $this->db->from('categories'); 
        $query = $this->db->get(); 
        $result = $query->result();
        return $result;
    }


    public function findAll(){
        return $this->db->get('products')->result();
    }

     public function findByCategory($id){
         $this->db->where('id', $id);
        return $this->db->get('categories')->result();
    }




}
?>
```

My Category_model file:

```
<?php


class Category_model extends CI_Model {

    public function findAll(){
        $this->db->get('categories')->result();
    }

    public function findByCategory($id)
    {
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $this->db->get('categories')->result();
        return $this->db->get('categories')->row();
    }

}


?>
```

My db_helper.php

```
<?php if (!function_exists('get_categories_h')) {
    function get_categories_h(){
        $CI = get_instance();
        $categories = $CI->Product_model->get_categories();
        return $categories;
    } } ?>
```

Some database information:

```
Table 1: 5 columns: products
-product_id
-product_naam
-product_beschrijving
-user_id
-category_id

table 2: categories: 2 columns:
1.id
2.name
```

Comment: replace `$category['id']` with `$category->id` and same for `name`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5412924/fatal-error-cannot-use-object-of-type-stdclass-as-array-in)

Comment: Hey I changed it to this:  <a href="<?php echo base_url('Product/category/'.$row->id);?>"> <?php echo $row->name; ?></a> and I'm now getting this error:  A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: row

Filename: views/allecadeaus.php

Line Number: 26

Backtrace:

Comment: No, you just have to use object notation for `id` and `name` . You can check in above link or below answer

Comment: remove unnecessary codes. Is your issue is in  product detail or product category?

Comment: So I mean when I click on a category in the category sidemenu bar this happens in the link: Product/category/1 and the view page does load but no product shows that belongs to that category and I'm getting this error: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Error

Message: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Filename: views/category.php

Line Number: 41

Comment: @JohnDoe122 `print_r $product` and post the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution for your problem:

Whole allecadeaus.php view file:

```
   <ul class="list-group">
         <?php foreach (get_categories_h() as $category) : ?>
             <li class="list-group-item">
                 <a href="<?php echo base_url().'Product/category/' . $category->id; ?>"> <?php echo $category->name; ?></a>
            </li>
         <?php endforeach; ?>
     </ul>
```

Comment: Hello, there is no more error on the allecadeaus.php view file anymore but when I click on a certain category link it shows this error: A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'category_id' in 'where clause'

SELECT * FROM `categories` WHERE `category_id` = '10'

Filename: models/Product_model.php

Line Number: 55

Comment: Please post your get_categories_h()  function file or Helper file and please change your query `SELECT * FROM categories WHERE id = '10'`

Comment: Okay Ill edited my question and showed my db_helper.php

Comment: check you category table . I think ID will be there instead of category_id.
Then query like this SELECT * FROM categories WHERE id = '10'

Comment: @mayankverma In above question mention table structure `table 2: categories: 2 columns: 1.id 2.name` so i can put that changes.

Comment: then put this query SELECT * FROM categories WHERE id = '10' instead of
SELECT * FROM `categories` WHERE `category_id` = '10'

Comment: OH yes true its id and not category_id . But now when I click on a category link i get this error: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Error

Message: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Filename: views/category.php

Line Number: 41

Comment: Please post your `views/category.php` file.

Comment: Check my edited question, I added my category.php view file and the error when I load that view file.

Comment: Hello Nikunj,

public function get_product_details($product_id) {
        $arrReturn = array();
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('products');
        $this->db->where('product_id', $product_id);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query->result_array();
        if (!empty($result)) {
            $arrReturn = $result[0];
        }
        return $arrReturn;
    }
When check if (!empty($result)) { } in that case you are fetching only one indexing data from the result array $result[0] thats why this problem is generating .

Comment: If are only one indexing result then you have no need to foreach loop there !

Comment: Than what should I do? do you also need my controller and model file to show products with foreach loop?

Comment: public function get_product_details($product_id) {
        $arrReturn = array();
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('products');
        $this->db->where('product_id', $product_id);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query->result_array();       
        return $arrReturn;
    }
Just do like this

Comment: Hello, unfortunately I'm still getting the same error on the category.php view page. Not able to load product information on that page

Comment: Please I think change `id` will be there instead of `category_id` as per your get_product_details function.

Comment: I dont have category_id in my get_product_details function

Comment: but your product table inside field name `category_id`

Comment: What do you mean? i have id instead of category_id

Answer (score 0):

is your database already have the filed category_id, is the name correct? can you show screen from your categories and products table?