# CodeIgniter category products not showing

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I made a side category menu bar in the CI framework and whenever I click on a category link it does go to the category view page and to the right link for example : Product/category/3   but it doesn't show the products that belong to for example the category_id = 3 .

Instead of showing certain products that belong to the category I'm getting this error message:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Error

Message: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Filename: views/category.php

Line Number: 41
```

This is line 41 in category.php:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>/Product/details/<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>">
```

So I'm guessing it means I can't echo product details on the category.php view page? But I'm not sure whats causing the problem.

This is the category.php view file:

```
<?php   include_once ('templates/header.php');  ?>

<!-- Alle cadeaus gele title bovenaan pagina -->

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 bg-warning" style="font-size:25px">
            <center>Alle cadeaus</center>
        </div>
        </div>
</div>

 <hr />

<br>

<!-- Cadeau categorie side menu -->
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div id="categorymenu">
                    <center>  <h3>Categorieën</h3> </center>
                    <ul class="list-group">
                         <?php foreach (get_categories_h() as $category) : ?>
             <li class="list-group-item">
                 <a href="<?php echo base_url().'Product/category/' . $category->id; ?>"> <?php echo $category->name; ?></a>
            </li>
         <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>




<!-- Laat cadeau zien op alle cadeaus pagina -->
<div class="col-md-8">
<?php foreach($products as $product) : ?>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div id="product">
        <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>/Product/details/<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>">
          <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>upload/<?php echo $product['product_foto_thumb']; ?>">
        </a>
        <div class="product_naam"><?php echo $product['product_naam']; ?></div>
        <div class="ophaal_plaats">
           <?php  echo $product['ophaal_plaats']; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="aangeboden_door">
            <p>Aangeboden door: Peter</p>
              </div>
        </div>
        </div>


<?php endforeach; ?>

</div>



<div class="clearfix"></div>

 <?php   include_once ('templates/footer.php');  ?>
```

My Product.php controller file:

```
<?php
 defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
 class Product extends CI_Controller { 


    var $data = array();

     public function index()
 {

  //Laad kado uploaden view
  $this->load->view('product_form', $this->data);
 }

 public function details($product_id)
 {
  //load the Product_model
  $this->load->model('Product_model');

  //call function getdata in de Product_model
  $data['userdetail_list'] = $this->Product_model->getdata();

  //get product details
  $data['product'] = $this->Product_model->get_product_details($product_id);

  //laad view
  $data['main_content'] = 'details';
  $this->load->view('details',$data); 
 }
 //categorie product function
 public function category($id)
 {
  $data['title'] = 'Category';
  $data['page'] = 'Product/category';
  $data['category'] = $this->Category_model->findByCategory($id);
  $data['products'] = $this->Product_model->findByCategory($id);
  $this->Category_model->findByCategory($id);
  $this->load->view('category', $data);
 }

 public function __construct()
 {
  parent::__construct();
  $this->load->model('Product_model');
  $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
 }
```

My Product_model file:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Product_model extends CI_model {

    public function saveProduct($data) { 
        $this->db->insert('products', $data);
        $product_id = $this->db->insert_id();
        return $product_id;
    }
      public function getdata()
    {
        $this->db->select('users.user_id,users.email,users.voornaam,products.product_id,products.category_id,products.product_naam');
        $this->db->from('users');
        $this->db->join('products','products.user_id = users.user_id');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if($query->num_rows()>0)
        {
           return $query->result_array();
        }
    }

    public function get_product_details($product_id) {
        $arrReturn = array();
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('products');
        $this->db->where('product_id', $product_id);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query->result_array();
        if (!empty($result)) {
            $arrReturn = $result[0];
        }
        return $arrReturn;
    }


    /*
      Get categories
     */
    public function get_categories(){
        $this->db->select('*'); 
        $this->db->from('categories'); 
        $query = $this->db->get(); 
        $result = $query->result();
        return $result;
    }


    public function findAll(){
        return $this->db->get('products')->result();
    }

     public function findByCategory($id){
         $this->db->where('id', $id);
        return $this->db->get('categories')->result();
    }




}
?>
```

Category_model file:

```
<?php


class Category_model extends CI_Model {

    public function findAll(){
        $this->db->get('categories')->result();
    }

    public function findByCategory($id)
    {
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $this->db->get('categories')->result();
        return $this->db->get('categories')->row();
    }

}


?>
```

My db_helper.php file (might be unnecessary code)

```
<?php if (!function_exists('get_categories_h')) {
    function get_categories_h(){
        $CI = get_instance();
        $categories = $CI->Product_model->get_categories();
        return $categories;
    } } ?>
```

(And some database table information if someone wants to see how my database looks like):

```
Table 1: 5 columns: products
-product_id
-product_naam
-product_beschrijving
-user_id
-category_id

table 2: categories: 2 columns:
1.id
2.name
```

When I print $products: () : 
(The text is so long because I wanted to have long product descriptions)

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [product_id] => 75 [product_naam] => Testcadeautje [product_beschrijving] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc, quis gravida magna mi a libero. Fusce vulputate eleifend sapien. Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus. Nullam accumsan lorem in dui. Cras ultricies mi eu turpis hendrerit fringilla. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; In ac dui quis mi consectetuer lacinia. Nam pretium turpis et arcu. Duis arcu tortor, suscipit eget, imperdiet nec, imperdiet iaculis, ipsum. Sed aliquam ultrices mauris. Integer ante arcu, accumsan a, consectetuer eget, posuere ut, mauris. Praesent adipiscing. Phasellus ullamcorper ipsum rutrum nunc. Nunc nonummy metus. Vestibulum volutpat pretium libero. Cras id dui. Aenean ut eros et nisl sagittis vestibulum. Nullam nulla eros, ultricies sit amet, nonummy id, imperdiet feugiat, pede. Sed lectus. Donec mollis hendrerit risus. Phasellus nec sem in justo pellentesque facilisis. Etiam imperdiet imperdiet orci. Nunc nec neque. Phasellus leo dolor, tempus non, auctor et, hendrerit quis, nisi. Curabitur ligula sapien, tincidunt non, euismod vitae, posuere imperdiet, leo. Maecenas malesuada. Praesent congue erat at massa. Sed cursus turpis vitae tortor. Donec posuere vulputate arcu. Phasellus accumsan cursus velit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Sed aliquam, nisi quis porttitor congue, elit erat euismod orci, ac placerat dolor lectus quis orci. Phasellus consectetuer vestibulum elit. Aenean tellus metus, bibendum sed, posuere ac, mattis non, nunc. Vestibulum fringilla pede sit amet augue. In turpis. Pellentesque posuere. Praesent turpis. Aenean posuere, tortor sed cursus feugiat, nunc augue blandit nunc, eu sollicitudin urna dolor sagittis lacus. Donec elit libero, sodales nec, volutpat a, suscipit non, turpis. Nullam sagittis. Suspendisse pulvinar, augue ac venenatis condimentum, sem libero volutpat nibh, nec pellentesque velit pede quis nunc. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Fusce id purus. Ut varius tincidunt libero. Phasellus dolor. Maecenas vestibulum mollis diam. Pellentesque ut neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. [user_id] => 4 [ophaal_plaats] => Arnhem [product_foto] => new_fda34b15a9652cc0d51b5f5a26fd4c84.jpg [product_foto_thumb] => thumb_fda34b15a9652cc0d51b5f5a26fd4c84.jpg [date_created] => 2017-10-04 [date_updated] => 2017-10-04 [category_id] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [product_id] => 76 [product_naam] => 100x100 foto [product_beschrijving] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc, quis gravida magna mi a libero. Fusce vulputate eleifend sapien. Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus. Nullam accumsan lorem in dui. Cras ultricies mi eu turpis hendrerit fringilla. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; In ac dui quis mi consectetuer lacinia. Nam pretium turpis et arcu. Duis arcu tortor, suscipit eget, imperdiet nec, imperdiet iaculis, ipsum. Sed aliquam ultrices mauris. Integer ante arcu, accumsan a, consectetuer eget, posuere ut, mauris. Praesent adipiscing. Phasellus ullamcorper ipsum rutrum nunc. Nunc nonummy metus. Vestibulum volutpat pretium libero. Cras id dui. Aenean ut eros et nisl sagittis vestibulum. Nullam nulla eros, ultricies sit amet, nonummy id, imperdiet feugiat, pede. Sed lectus. Donec mollis hendrerit risus. Phasellus nec sem in justo pellentesque facilisis. Etiam imperdiet imperdiet orci. Nunc nec neque. Phasellus leo dolor, tempus non, auctor et, hendrerit quis, nisi. Curabitur ligula sapien, tincidunt non, euismod vitae, posuere imperdiet, leo. Maecenas malesuada. Praesent congue erat at massa. Sed cursus turpis vitae tortor. Donec posuere vulputate arcu. Phasellus accumsan cursus velit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Sed aliquam, nisi quis porttitor congue, elit erat euismod orci, ac placerat dolor lectus quis orci. Phasellus consectetuer vestibulum elit. Aenean tellus metus, bibendum sed, posuere ac, mattis non, nunc. Vestibulum fringilla pede sit amet augue. In turpis. Pellentesque posuere. Praesent turpis. Aenean posuere, tortor sed cursus feugiat, nunc augue blandit nunc, eu sollicitudin urna dolor sagittis lacus. Donec elit libero, sodales nec, volutpat a, suscipit non, turpis. Nullam sagittis. Suspendisse pulvinar, augue ac venenatis condimentum, sem libero volutpat nibh, nec pellentesque velit pede quis nunc. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Fusce id purus. Ut varius tincidunt libero. Phasellus dolor. Maecenas vestibulum mollis diam. Pellentesque ut neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. [user_id] => 4 [ophaal_plaats] => Amsterdam [product_foto] => new_b5fb5053c4374f35eda29cc70bc9f6a5.png [product_foto_thumb] => thumb_b5fb5053c4374f35eda29cc70bc9f6a5.png [date_created] => 2017-10-04 [date_updated] => 2017-10-04 [category_id] => 9 ) [2] => Array ( [product_id] => 77 [product_naam] => Testcadeau [product_beschrijving] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc, quis gravida magna mi a libero. Fusce vulputate eleifend sapien. Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus. Nullam accumsan lorem in dui. Cras ultricies mi eu turpis hendrerit fringilla. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; In ac dui quis mi consectetuer lacinia. Nam pretium turpis et arcu. Duis arcu tortor, suscipit eget, imperdiet nec, imperdiet iaculis, ipsum. Sed aliquam ultrices mauris. Integer ante arcu, accumsan a, consectetuer eget, posuere ut, mauris. Praesent adipiscing. Phasellus ullamcorper ipsum rutrum nunc. Nunc nonummy metus. Vestibulum volutpat pretium libero. Cras id dui. Aenean ut eros et nisl sagittis vestibulum. Nullam nulla eros, ultricies sit amet, nonummy id, imperdiet feugiat, pede. Sed lectus. Donec mollis hendrerit risus. Phasellus nec sem in justo pellentesque facilisis. Etiam imperdiet imperdiet orci. Nunc nec neque. Phasellus leo dolor, tempus non, auctor et, hendrerit quis, nisi. [user_id] => 4 [ophaal_plaats] => Testing [product_foto] => new_6c1bed3faeb30af3d3c0f57af902b03a.jpg [product_foto_thumb] => thumb_6c1bed3faeb30af3d3c0f57af902b03a.jpg [date_created] => 2017-10-05 [date_updated] => 2017-10-05 [category_id] => 4 ) [3] => Array ( [product_id] => 78 [product_naam] => Testingcadeau [product_beschrijving] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc, quis gravida magna mi a libero. Fusce vulputate eleifend sapien. Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus. Nullam accumsan lorem in dui. Cras ultricies mi eu turpis hendrerit fringilla. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; In ac dui quis mi consectetuer lacinia. Nam pretium turpis et arcu. Duis arcu tortor, suscipit eget, imperdiet nec, imperdiet iaculis, ipsum. Sed aliquam ultrices mauris. Integer ante arcu, accumsan a, consectetuer eget, posuere ut, mauris. Praesent adipiscing. Phasellus ullamcorper ipsum rutrum nunc. Nunc nonummy metus. Vestibulum volutpat pretium libero. Cras id dui. Aenean ut eros et nisl sagittis vestibulum. Nullam nulla eros, ultricies sit amet, nonummy id, imperdiet feugiat, pede. Sed lectus. Donec mollis hendrerit risus. Phasellus nec sem in justo pellentesque facilisis. Etiam imperdiet imperdiet orci. Nunc nec neque. Phasellus leo dolor, tempus non, auctor et, hendrerit quis, nisi. [user_id] => 4 [ophaal_plaats] => Teststad [product_foto] => new_a259245f58b92408783584ea4b7d2713.jpg [product_foto_thumb] => thumb_a259245f58b92408783584ea4b7d2713.jpg [date_created] => 2017-10-05 [date_updated] => 2017-10-05 [category_id] => 1 ) [4] => Array ( [product_id] => 79 [product_naam] => Testingcadeau [product_beschrijving] => Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc, quis gravida magna mi a libero. Fusce vulputate eleifend sapien. Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus. Nullam accumsan lorem in dui. Cras ultricies mi eu turpis hendrerit fringilla. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; In ac dui quis mi consectetuer lacinia. Nam pretium turpis et arcu. Duis arcu tortor, suscipit eget, imperdiet nec, imperdiet iaculis, ipsum. Sed aliquam ultrices mauris. Integer ante arcu, accumsan a, consectetuer eget, posuere ut, mauris. Praesent adipiscing. Phasellus ullamcorper ipsum rutrum nunc. Nunc nonummy metus. Vestibulum volutpat pretium libero. Cras id dui. Aenean ut eros et nisl sagittis vestibulum. Nullam nulla eros, ultricies sit amet, nonummy id, imperdiet feugiat, pede. Sed lectus. Donec mollis hendrerit risus. Phasellus nec sem in justo pellentesque facilisis. Etiam imperdiet imperdiet orci. Nunc nec neque. Phasellus leo dolor, tempus non, auctor et, hendrerit quis, nisi. [user_id] => 4 [ophaal_plaats] => Rotterdam-Zuid [product_foto] => new_59129cf7c3647901115b37a26315cafd.jpg [product_foto_thumb] => thumb_59129cf7c3647901115b37a26315cafd.jpg [date_created] => 2017-10-05 [date_updated] => 2017-10-05 [category_id] => 6 ) )
```

New error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$product_id

Filename: views/category.php

Line Number: 41

Backtrace:

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/application/views/category.php
Line: 41
Function: _error_handler

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/application/controllers/Product.php
Line: 38
Function: view

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once


A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Error

Message: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Filename: views/category.php

Line Number: 42

Backtrace:
```

Comment: try this `<?php echo $product->product_id; ?>`

Comment: Try change this `result_array()` to `result()` https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html

Comment: Getting this error if I try that: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$product_id

Filename: views/category.php

Line Number: 41

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Product category function not working in CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46704897/product-category-function-not-working-in-codeigniter)

Comment: @JohnDoe122 you find answer? i edit my answer...

Answer (score 0):

In your product model change your findByCategory function:

```
public function findByCategory($id){
              $this->db->select('*'); 
              $this->db->where('id', $id);
              $q = $this->db->get('products');
              if($q->num_rows() > 0) { 
                  foreach ($q->result() as $row) { 
                      $data[] = $row; 
                  }
                  return $data; 
              } 
          }
```

and your Category_model need to change:

```
public function findByCategory($id)
          {
              $this->db->select('*'); 
              $this->db->where('id', $id);
              $q = $this->db->get('categories');
              if($q->num_rows() > 0) { 
                  foreach ($q->result() as $row) { 
                      $data[] = $row; 
                  }
                  return $data; 
              } 
          }
```

The problem is because your product_model function you get categories table but there is only `id, name` only so you need to fetch the data in products table.

Comment: Hello I tried you're code and still getting this error: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Error

Message: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Filename: views/category.php

Line Number: 41

Comment: Print and Show your `$products` result @JohnDoe122

Comment: Ok I tried to do this : 
<?php print $products; ?>  on the category.php view page but I don't see anything appearing when I load the view

Comment: that is not syntax try this `<?php print_r( $products); exit; ?>`

Comment: Hello, I tried it and it does work. It shows all the product information

Comment: Of all products

Comment: Show the result

Comment: now you tell what you get when run this inside `foreach` line `<?php  print_r($product['product_id']); exit; ?>` @JohnDoe122

Comment: Ill edit my answer and show the full Error I'm receiving when I try that line

Comment: now you try this `<?php echo $product->product_id ?>` or `<?php echo $product[0]->product_id ?>` @JohnDoe122

Comment: And the first one I also get this error: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$product_id

Filename: views/category.php

Line Number: 41

Comment: try your url Product/category/75 @JohnDoe122

Comment: Getting this error if I try that A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: views/category.php

Line Number: 38

Backtrace:

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/application/views/category.php
Line: 38
Function: _error_handler

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/application/controllers/Product.php
Line: 38
Function: view

File: /home/ubuntu/workspace/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

Comment: No no try 2 instead of 75

Comment: So you mean when I type product/category 2 right? Ill edit my question to show. still same 2 errors

Comment: Ok look at bottom of my question to see the errors when i type product/category/2 in my url